# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un JSON en una matriz?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pandas, diccionarios

De un proceso de raster, estoy obteniendo esta salida como resultado. Está recortada a unos pocos resultados ya que en realidad son mas de 13500 datos.

```
{"1981.01.01.tif": [{"properties": {"ID": 1}, "mean": 0.8401072025299072}, {"properties": {"ID": 2}, "mean": 0.9933649897575378}], "1981.01.02.tif": [{"properties": {"ID": 1}, "mean": 0.5100491046905518}, {"properties": {"ID": 2}, "mean": 0.2550245523452759}]}
```

Lo que estoy buscando obtener con Panda o SQL o CSV, cualquiera de la formas una salida donde:

```
                      1          2
1981.01.01  0.840107203 0.993364989
1981.01.02  0.510049105 0.255024552
```

Donde los encabezados de cada columna son los numeros ID, los de cada fila el texto antes de cada .tif.

Comment: Que tiene desarollado hasta el momento para resolver esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que recorrer tu diccionario, e ir almacenando en una lista los índices (que son las claves del diccionario, quitándoles la extensión `.tif`), mientras que en otra lista vas almacenando los valores de cada fila, que extraes iterando por la lista asociada a cada clave, recopilando en otro diccionario la información. Este segundo diccionario tendría como claves los ID, y como valores las `"mean"`.

El siguiente bucle hace esto:

```
indices = []  # Lista con los índices (1981.01.01, etc.)
datos = []   # Lista de diccionarios, cada uno con claves=IDs, valores=mean
for k,v in results.items():
  indices.append(k.rsplit(".",1)[0])  # Quitamos la extensión .tif
  fila = {}           # Diccionario que guardará los datos de esta fila
  for dato in v:      # que recopilamos así
    id = dato["properties"]["ID"]
    mean = dato["mean"]
    fila.update({id: mean})
  datos.append(fila)
```

El resultado del procesamiento dejará esto en la variable `indices`:

```
['1981.01.01', '1981.01.02']
```

Y esto en la variable `datos`:

```
[{1: 0.8401072025299072, 2: 0.9933649897575378},
 {1: 0.5100491046905518, 2: 0.2550245523452759}]
```

A partir de esta nueva estructura, es trivial crear un dataframe pandas:

```
>>> print(pd.DataFrame(datos, index=indices))
                   1         2
1981.01.01  0.840107  0.993365
1981.01.02  0.510049  0.255025
```

Comment: Gracias!. La consulto pudo haber sido muy básica, pero me he metido de lleno hace muy poco en Python.

Comment: Una consulta nueva, por el tipo de proceso que estoy corriendo (trabajando con mapas y rasters), en ese diccionario de salida, aparecen valores  que no están asociados a 'properties'. Esto hace que el codigo tire KeyError y no continua. Siendo que esos valores no me sirvern, Que me recomiendas? {"1981.01.01.tif": [{"properties": {"ID": 1}, "mean": 0.8401072025299072}, {"properties": {"ID": 2}, "mean": 0.9933649897575378}], "1981.01.02.tif": [{"properties": {"ID": 1}, "mean": 0.5100491046905518}, {"properties": {"ID": 2}, "mean": 0.2550245523452759}, {'mean': None}, {'mean': None}]}